# Github action exclude submodule from being build/tested by .net

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using another Git Repo as library, which uses a different `.net` Version and has missing Permissions to be build on Action.
How do i exclude this/all sub modules from being built ?

Error Codes being Produced:

```
error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "obj/Debug/". Access to the path '/home/runner/work/Repo/Project/Submodule/Folder/obj/Debug/' is denied.
```

```
error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v2.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application...
```

Workflow File (dotnet.yml)

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: textbook/git-checkout-submodule-action@master
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```